# ng build using specific configuration

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

[update] 
This seems to only happen in VS Code terminal, where as from a console window, it works as expected!  arrrgh

ng run build-dev works fine

ng run build-prod however does not.  What am I missing?

I get this when I run the build-prod command

> Cannot determine project or target for command. Error: Cannot
>   determine project or target for command.

In my project.json, I have this in the scripts section

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-dev": "ng build --prod=false --configuration=dev",
    "build-qa": "ng build --prod=false --configuration=qa",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod=true --configuration=prod",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Dflood.Genesys.Web.App:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

In my angular.json, I have this in the config section

```
 "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: Did you do `ng run build-dev` not `npm run build-dev`?